# Unity animation changes position after repositioning or resizing sprite

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a simple animation that changes the sprite's `position` `x`.

It works well, but when I **reposition the sprite** or **resize the sprite** using the editor, I see that the animation's `position` values were **not changed**, leading to the sprite to jump over to the previous position.

Here's a snapshot of the animation's keyframes, showing that the starting position is `0`.

[image]

After I move the sprite around the scence, these value **remain `0`**, and when the animation starts, the sprite moves back to position `0,0,0`.

Is there any way to set the animation's `position` values relative? or make it change automatically when I change the sprite's position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values assigned in the Animator always override values assigned in the Editor or in the `Update` or `FixedUpdate` methods.

The easiest way to solve your problem is probably by making the `GameObject` a child-object of another new `Gameobject`. That way the positions are changed relative to that parent-object and you can just change the position of the parent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The animations are for several sprites under an empty gameobject. But when I move them, I need to move them seperatly, because I can't move the whole gameobject. What am I missing here? Is there a way to strict them under the gameobject so I can move them all at once?

Comment: Hmm maybe try putting the empty gameobject under another empty gameobject and move that one. It should move them all at once

Comment: Already tried that and still the same. From the heirarchy menu I chose Create > Create Empty, then drag the sprites under it.

Comment: Never mind it was changing the parnt's coordinates in a script. It works now. Thanks !

Comment: @Ali Baba creating empty parent gameobject will break the animations :(